# Removing duplicates from Array with C#.NET 4.0 LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, duplicates, distinct

I have this c# code that builds a string of comma seperated matches for a service:

```
for (m = r.Match(site); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
     found = found + "," + m.Value.Replace(",", "");
}
return found;
```

Output looks like: aaa,bbb,ccc,aaa,111,111,ccc

Now that code is on .NET 4.0 How can I use C# LINQ to remove duplicates?

Also, Any way to remove duplicates without changing order?

I found this sample code in another post, but not sure exactly how to apply it:

```
int[] s = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 4}; 
int[] q = s.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, first put the strings you find into an array, see if that helps.  You're building up a long string, that won't make it easy to find or remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] s = found.Split(',').Distinct().ToArray()
```

Comment: Thanks.  And in 4.0, to return s  as a single comma sperated string now?

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the code that builds the result to output it directly.

ie. rewrite this:

```
for (m = r.Match(site); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
{
     found = found + "," + m.Value.Replace(",", "");
}
return found;
```

To this:

```
return (from Match m in r.Matches(site)
        select m.Value.Replace(",", "")).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This will return an array. If you still want it back as a string:

```
return string.Join(", ", (from Match m in r.Matches(site)
        select m.Value.Replace(",", "")).Distinct().ToArray());
```

You may or may not be able to remove the last `.ToArray()` from the last code there depending on the .NET runtime version. .NET 4.0 `string.Join(...)` can take an `IEnumerable<string>`, whereas previous versions requires an array.

Answer (score 4):

This will return a string of comma seperated values without duplicates:

```
var result = string.Join(",",
    r.Matches(site)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value.Replace(",", string.Empty))
        .Distinct()
    );
```

Comment: For .NET before 4.0, you need to add `.ToArray()` after distinct.

Answer (score 4):

this could be one possible solution:

```
var data = new List<string>();
for (m = r.Match(site); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
  data.Add(m.Value.Replace(",", ""));
return String.Join(",", data.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a single LINQ query

```
string strSentence = "aaa,bbb,ccc,aaa,111,111,ccc";
List<string> results = (from w in strSentence.Split(',') select w).Distinct().ToList();
```